# Mongodb remove all the Address from records

Tags: mongodb

I want to remove all the address object from these records. 
In some records, address object doesn't exist.

```
db.name.insert([ 
    {  "_id" : ObjectId("5a898f6c49bf66c10a70ed0d"),  "first_name" : "Sandeep",  "last_name" : "kumar",  "age" : 30.0 },
    {  "_id" : ObjectId("5a863f6c49bf66c10a70ed0f"),  "first_name" : "Dev",  "last_name" : "singh",  "age" : 31.0 },
    {  "_id" : ObjectId("5a878f6c49bf66c10a70ed0e"),  "first_name" : "Ram",  "last_name" : "Sharma",  "age" : 31.0,  "Address" : { "Pincode" : 1234.0 }
    },
    {  "_id" : ObjectId("5a864f6c49bf66c10a70ed0e"),  "first_name" : "him",  "last_name" : "Sharma",  "age" : 31.0,  "Address" : { "Pincode" : 45787 } },
    {  "_id" : ObjectId("5a864f6c49bf66c10a70ed0e"),  "first_name" : "him",  "last_name" : "Sharma",  "age" : 31.0,  "Address" : { "Pincode" : 7899, "City" : "Delhi" } }

])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) operator

```
db.name.update({}, { $unset: { "Address": 1 } }, { multi: true })
```

You want all documents to be affected so you should specify `multi: true`